# Complex interpolation and distributive law

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $X, Y, Z$ be separable complex Banach spaces.
I'm wondering whether the following holds or not:
$$
[X\cap Y,Z]_\theta =[X, Z]_\theta \cap [Y,Z]_\theta,
$$
where $\theta \in [0,1]$ and $[A,B]_\theta$ is the standard complex interpolation.
This claim seems natural, and it is true in the endpoint case. Could you please tell me whether it holds or not in the general case?

Comment: It does not hold in general. For $\Omega$ a smooth bounded domain, let's take a look at $Z=\mathrm{L}^2(\Omega)$, $X=\mathrm{H}^1_0(\Omega)$, and $Y=\mathrm{H}^1_\sigma(\Omega)$ (free divergence Sobolev functions) then we have for $s<1/2$
$$X\cap Y = \mathrm{H}^1_{0,\sigma}(\Omega) \text{ and } [Z,X\cap Y]_s= \mathrm{H}^s_{0,\sigma}(\Omega)$$ While, $$[Z,Y]_s\cap [Z,X]_s= \mathrm{H}^s_{\sigma}(\Omega) \cap \mathrm{H}^s(\Omega)=\mathrm{H}^s_{\sigma}(\Omega).$$
Which are two different spaces.